# Merging binary data

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I'm reformatting this question to be shorter and to the point. If I run a bunch of different custom objects through BinaryFormatter's Serialize method, I will get a bunch of serialized binary files. What is the best way to merge these binary files/retrieve them using Save/Load functionality in my app?

Comment: Since Binary Serialization is so fast, why not just load it, change what you want, and then save it again?

Comment: Deserializing back into objects doesn't make sense. All I want to do is merge those files into 1 file and then later on split them up.

In terms of what you asked, I, in that 1 new file to be saved, will include a series of characters indicating the number of files originally merged. Thus, later on I can use some method to split that 1 large file back into its separate pieces.

Comment: One more thing, the main thing I'm concerned about is not necessarily the merging process but just making sure that the way I merge it will not in anyway mess up the way in which the data was represented. In addition, after splitting that large file, all of my files contains are identical to how they were before the merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to make all those custom objects inherit from a single interface of your choosing.
Then make a class that will hold a list of objects of that interface.
Then, serialize that container class.
That is equivalent to what you're asking for, which is merge binaries together.
Instead of trying to do that, just one make a class that creates the binaries already together, without having to merge them later.

Is that what you're asking?